# Unable to start embedded Tomcat server - Invalid keystore format

Tags: spring-boot, ssl

**I get this error when I add keystore.jks to the resource directory.
I am facing this when I run spring-boot application in command line.
In IntelliJ IDEA app is running without any issue.**

2020-11-08 21:37:05.776 ERROR 2422 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:185) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:554) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at net.nidmi.web.WebReplyApplication.main(WebReplyApplication.java:22) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[web-reply-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107) ~[web-reply-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[web-reply-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[web-reply-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:229) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:43) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:282) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:213) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1067) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid keystore format
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:99) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:216) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1141) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:592) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1064) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
at java.base/sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:667) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:222) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1479) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.security.KeyStoreUtil.load(KeyStoreUtil.java:69) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getStore(SSLUtilBase.java:216) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate.getCertificateKeystore(SSLHostConfigCertificate.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:282) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:246) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar!/:9.0.38]
... 34 common frames omitted

Answer (score 0):

When jar file created, I checked the target directory, keystore.jks file in classpath was not recognized!!!
I just physically copied JKS file in target and resolved.